# How do we access the content of 2-d array using pointer to array

Tags: c, pointers

I have an 2-D array and i wanted to access the particular element of this array using pointer to array something like this below

```
 main()
 {
  int a[][4]={{2 ,0 ,0 ,2},{41 ,0, 0, 9}};

  int (*p)[4]=a;
  printf("%d",*p[0]);
  }
```

This gives me the first element of Ist 1-d array but now access 2nd element of 1-d array using pointer to array?

Comment: No i tried it already it gives me 1st element of 2nd 2-D array

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access the elements of your 2d arrays like this:

```
printf("%d", a[0][1]); /* prints second item of first array */
```

Answer (score 1):

`a[x][y]` gets compiled into `*(a+x*4+y)`.

Answer (score 0):

The elements are accessed using the corresponding row and column numbers.

If u have to access the second element of the first row in the 2-D array mentioned above,
then you can use

printf("%d",a[2][1]);

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[2][4]={{2 ,0 ,0 ,2},{41 ,0, 0, 9}};
int (*p)[4]=a;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        printf("%d\n", p[i][j]);
```

You can access the array elements with `p` as if it was `a`.
The reason for that is simply because when you use the name `a` in a value context, its type is already `int (*)[4]`, so the same type as p.

Note that the `p[i][j]` form in C is equivalent to `*(*p + i) + j)`.